# Multipart data send object type file

Tags: angular, file, multipartform-data, primeng

I'm trying to send multiple files to my rest API. 
So in my html where I use PrimeNG, there is :

```
<p-fileUpload #fileInput name="myfiles[]"  customUpload="true" (uploadHandler)="myUploader($event)"
                    multiple="multiple" accept="*" maxFileSize="2000000"
                    showUploadButton="false" cancelLabel="Annuler" chooseLabel="Choisir">            
</p-fileUpload>
```

In my angular ts file I'm calling my rest API like this :

```
saveData(data, uploadedFiles): Observable<any> {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("uploadedFiles", uploadedFiles);
    formData.append("data",JSON.stringify(data));
    return this.http.post(apiUrl + "/" , formData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

So if i log `uploadedFiles` I get :

[image]

If I develop `File` I have :

[image]

So I can see that I've correctly got my uploaded file.

But when I send the POST request, I can see that my data send is :
[image]

I think that's why in my rest API, when I try to get **fileNames**, they are `null`

Here is how I implemented my rest API :

```
    @POST
    @Path("/")
    @Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
    public Response createClink(@FormDataParam("data") MyData myData,
                                @FormDataParam("uploadedFiles") List<FormDataBodyPart> bodyParts,
                                @FormDataParam("uploadedFiles") FormDataContentDisposition fileDispositions) {
        StringBuffer fileDetails = new StringBuffer("");
        /* Save multiple files */

        for (int i = 0; i < bodyParts.size(); i++) {
            BodyPartEntity bodyPartEntity = (BodyPartEntity) bodyParts.get(i).getEntity();
            String fileName = bodyParts.get(i).getContentDisposition().getFileName();
            System.err.println("fileName");
            System.err.println(fileName);

            //saveFile(bodyPartEntity.getInputStream(), fileName);  
       }            
    }
```

**So why my file objects are not sent correctly ? How can I do this ? 
Is there another mistake ?**

Answer (score 0):

So I had problems both front and back. 
In front I did :

```
saveData(data, uploadedFiles): Observable<any> {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("data",JSON.stringify(data));
    for (let i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
      formData.append("uploadedFiles", uploadedFiles[i], uploadedFiles[i].name);
    }
    return this.http.post(apiUrl + "/" , formData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

And back I'd put only one list, so this is my solution :

```
public Response create(@FormDataParam("data") MyData myData,
                                @FormDataParam("uploadedFiles") List<FormDataBodyPart> bodyParts,
                                @FormDataParam("uploadedFiles") List<FormDataContentDisposition> fileDispositions) {
}
```